# Does every geometric shape have an apothem?

Tags: geometry, definition

Does every arbitrary geometric shape have an apothem? This is not entirely clear to me.

(I have heard that the apothem of a geometric shape is a generalization of the notion of the radius of a circle.)

Comment: Is a circle a geometric shape?  a line?  an Archimedean spiral?

Comment: What's your definition of apothem? From [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apothem) I don't see how you can apply this to anything but a regular polygon. That's not a very "arbitrary" shape.

Answer (score 1):

An apothem is usually defined for regular polygons, where the idea of "center" is entirely unambiguous. For more irregular shapes, how do we define a center?

Even in cases where the center is clear, it's not hard to construct a polygon that has no segment from the center perpendicular to a side. On the $xy$-plane, join the sequence of points: $(3,0),(1,1),(0,3),(-1,1),(-3,0),(-1,-1),(0,-3),(1,-1),(3,0)$. This is an octagon shaped like a four-pointed star. The origin is its center, but you can't drop a perpendicular from there to any side.

Comment: Can't you drop perpendicular to extended line segments as apothem is the distance between side and center.

Comment: You could do that, sure, but would it count as an apothem? You could extend the definition in that way, if you want to. I was just providing an example of a polygon that doesn't have an apothem, as I understand its usual definition. Calling what you're describing the "distance between side and center" seems to be a non-standard use of "distance", though. Is the distance of the point $(100,1)$ from the unit square equal to $0$?

Comment: You said you can't drop a perpendicular from origin to any side, which is false.I was pointing only that. For me general definition is that apothem is length of inradius which is only possible in irregular polygons

Comment: By "side", I meant the line segment, not the extended segment. I think that's the usual use of the word. What I said wasn't "false"; you just seem to be using a strange definition of "side" of a polygon. You can't drop a perpendicular from the point $(2,2)$ to any side of the unit square, but you can drop perpendiculars to the lines that contain the sides of the unit square.

Comment: You are correct but the general meaning of a side is that line which contains it.

Comment: Says who? You're choosing preferred or convenient definitions and them claiming that they're somehow universal or general. I say the general definition of the side of a polygon is the line segment; you say it's the line. What makes you right?

Comment: What makes you right? There are loads of definitions which contain side as line. Definition of perpendicular dropped from a vertex of triangle to a side, in an obtuse angle 2 of them are on extended sides. We would be unable to find orthocenter if we took only line segment. Menelaus theorem also uses the same definition.

Comment: I’m not claiming to be “right”. I’m saying that it’s clear we’re using terms differently. Rather than insisting that one is wrong, why not act like a mathematician, step back, and acknowledge that different definitions can be used, leading to different results. It’s ok; you can be “right” without insisting that people using different definitions are “wrong”.

Comment: Yes it can be there.

Answer (score 0):

Apothem is radius of inradius of a polygon. Every polygon can't have a incircle in it.
Therefore every polygon can't have a apothem.